Redis timeout when there are a large number of keys
My WebAPI is written using the .NET framework 4.7.2 and i also use RedisStackChange 2.8.0.
I had a problem when the number of keys in redis reached about 7 million keys:

StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET (5000ms), next: GET xxx, inst: 15, qu: 0, qs: 3, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 132, serverEndpoint: 10.xx.xx.xx:xxxx, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 7 of 10 available, clientName: XXXX-XXXX, IOCP: (Busy=9,Free=991,Min=16,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=146,Free=32621,Min=16,Max=32767)

This causes the application to slow down a lot, I increased the timeout from 5s to 30s to fix the problem (Redis and API share the same server - 48 GB RAM).
I wonder if there is a better way to handle it?
This is my first time asking a question, thanks for reading
This is a condensed version of my code:
public class RedisClient : IDisposable
{
    private ConnectionMultiplexer _connection;

    public RedisClient()
    {
        Connect();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        var configuration = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["REDIS_CONN_STRING"]);
        _connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
    }

    public static RedisClient GetReConnectInstance()
    {
        if (_redisClient == null)
        {
            _redisClient = new RedisClient();
        }

        return _redisClient;
    }
    
    private static RedisClient _redisClient;
    
    public static RedisClient GetInstance()
    {
        if (_redisClient == null)
        {
            _redisClient = new RedisClient();
        }

        return _redisClient;
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Close();                
        }

    }
}

public class RedisCacheManager
{
    private IDatabase _db;
    private IMinvoiceDbContext _minvoiceDbContext;

    public RedisCacheManager(IMinvoiceDbContext minvoiceDbContext)
    {
        _minvoiceDbContext = minvoiceDbContext;

        try
        {
            RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.GetInstance();
            _db = redisClient.Database();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("RedisCacheManager", ex);
            ReconnectDB();
        }
    }
    
    private void ReconnectDB()
    {
        try
        {
            RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.GetReConnectInstance();
            _db = redisClient.Database();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("ReconnectDB", ex);
        }

    }
    
    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string key)
    {
        T rs = default(T);

        try
        {
            var rValue = await _db.StringGetAsync(key);

            if (!rValue.HasValue)
                return default(T);

            rs = Deserialize<T>(rValue);
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"Get: {key}", ex);
            ReconnectDB();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Get", ex);
        }
        return rs;
    }
}

// WHEN I USE REDIS
RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(_minvoiceDbContext);
string old = await cacheManager.Get<string>(CacheKeyManager.CHECK_TAX_CODE_OLD);


GetInstance and GetReConnectInstance share identical code. I am confident this doesn't do what you expect, but it should also not be related to the timeout problem. It's just another one.

The number of keys by itself doesn't usually have any impact on redis - at least not regular redis (if you're using some other RESP provider that uses a different engine internally, that's harder to comment on).
The main time that the number of keys is relevant is if you're issuing commands like KEYS, which are notoriously painful to the server for large databases. I can't see any KEYS usage above, but for all we know: some other application on the same server is using KEYS; since KEYS blocks the server (not individual connections): it impacts all clients on the same server. To check whether this is a cause, or indeed to identify any other commands that are impacting the server, you can use the SLOWLOG GET command on the server (typically via redis-cli or similar).
If the problem isn't individual commands blocking the server, another potential bottleneck is bandwidth; if you are getting/setting very large payloads, it is possible to saturate the connection. Since SE.Redis is a multiplexer, it is susceptible to head-of-line blocking, meaning: if you issue 10 GET commands, and the second one is for a huge payload, then the 8 behind that big one could timeout even if they are for tiny payloads. So: understanding the size of your payloads would also be relevant.
A final option to investigate is simply: is the server saturated? How many requests-per-second is it processing? And what level of CPU is it using? In particular, "hosted" redis options, especially at the lower price-point, tend to have fairly restrictive CPU limits, which it is easy to encroach upon. It could simply be that the server is being throttled by your host/provider environment, causing commands to "back up".

I don't use any KEYS command, it's simply Get Set KeyExists. At the time of timeout, the CPU only reached ~40%, and last thing, the data in my redis has a simple structure: KEY-VALUE(string of 32 characters)
